# Class diagram for an hospital

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I want to create a database for a hospital:

- The database should
  keep information on its staff, namely doctors and nurses.
  Information should also be kept on the hospital's users, the consultations appointments, the appointment booking system, the prescriptions/exams prescribed by the doctor during each appointment.
- Each doctor should have a
  specialty (e.g. orthopedics, dermatology, etc.) and that an appointment is always booked for a specific specialty.

My diagram is in Portuguese, so here the translations for the key elements: Doutor = Doctor, Enfermeira = Nurse, Consulta = Appointment, Exame = Examination, Prescrição = Prescription.

I would like to know if the requirements above are appropriately represented.  Can anyone tell me  if there's anything wrong with it and how I can improve it?
[image: Uml Scheme]

Comment: The question is rather broad.  I edited slightly to narrow it down. But if you can make it even more specific, it would be appreciated :-)

Comment: SO is no place for reviews (especially not for homework to be proven before given to the teacher). Please focus on a single question and read the help about what kind of questions can be asked here.

Answer (score 1):

When analysing such a problem, you need to make the distinction between what is relevant for the system and the database and what is relevant for the real life only:

- A `Booking system` is not something in the database. The booking system may use the database or some part of it, but most probably, it's not worth to show it in the class diagram representing the domain entities.  The dashed line connected to an association has a very specific meaning (association class).
- Similarly, the `Hospital`  and its associations make sense only if your system needs to deal with several hospitals.  If this is not the case, keep the design simple: remove the class from the diagram,  or keep the class isolated, as it would have a single instance, and everything else in the database would be for that hospital.
- Make a difference between real life users and `User [account]` in your system.  Isn't it meant that  each `Doctor`, `Nurse` or other `Staff` has  somehow a `User` account ?
- What I miss are the `Patient`, because I think that it's not only the patients who are users. Or did you mean that `User` were user of the hospital, i.e. `Patients` ?  I would strongly suggest to clarify this. By the way,  `Exam` will certainly be for a patient as well.
- I also miss the `Speciality` .  I see a couple of strings here and there, called `especialidade`.  But if all these strings refer to the same specialities, and these specialities are important for the management of the hospital,  then you'd better make it an own class.

A last general remark: `PK` is not UML.  I'd suggest to use a stereotype  `«PK»` which is popular in UML profiles for database design, or my favourite, a trailing `{id}` property that is defined in standard UML and tells that the attribute is part of the identifier for the class, without any more semantics.

THe multiplicities seem to make sense, with the following practical limitations if your system manages several hospitals:  when a staff changes from one to the other hospital,  you'd need to create a new staff, because otherwise you would loose all the history related to the doctor in the old hospital.  Similarly,  is a same real life person would be user dealing with several hospitals, this person would need several hospital specific User accounts (unless you change the association to a many to many one).